# I installed reFInd on my macbook pro 2016 with --alldrivers and now it powers up with a black screen

Tags: macos, ubuntu

I tried to install Ubuntu on another partition, reFInd was working fine but after selecting Install Ubuntu only a black screen showed up. I used `nomodeset` but it didn't work either. So I thought `./install.sh --alldrivers` would work I reinstalled reFInd and now my macbook powers up into a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Alright the CMD + ALT + R + P solved the problem I uninstalled reFInd if anybody got Ubuntu working on Macbook Pro 2016 please let me know ty